# How do I make a molecular "cloth" which I can drop some objects onto?

Tags: mesh, collision

Basically what I want to try to create is similar to this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UhuOsg06oOs&list=LLl-SOEftSFSK6xy1vylYL8g&index=8&t=0s

I've downloaded molecular and cube surfer.

I don't care about the reflections, colors etc. I just want to try to recreate the physics.

I think I need to create an emitter which produces all the balls into a grid. But then I also need to attach this to something, so it won't drop - plus I need to make so other objects can drop onto it and make it move.

I'm lost. Spend the last two full days trying to wrap my head around this.

Answer (score 1):

Emitter sounds a little like over complicating things. Here was my process.

1. Create a plane with ~20 subdivisions. Add vertices that will be pinned to a vertex group.
2. Enable cloth physics for plane and enable pinning with the vertex group that was created as option.
3. Animate an object moving or add a rigid body that will collide with the cloth and enable collision in the physics tab.
4. Create the molecular object (Smoothed sphere in our case) and parent it to the cloth plane object.
5. In the Object tab of the properties find duplication. Choose verts or faces. Make sure both objects are in the same layer as it will only display if they are.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the tip. If I do it like you suggest and drop several spheres onto the cloth - will it be possible for some of the spheres to break through the cloth?

What I'm trying to make in the end is some figures bouncing on a trampoline/safety net - and then at some point, some of the figures should fall through the trampoline because of the net breaks in several places.

I thought the best way to accomplish this would be to create some kind of mesh like the one above for objects to collide with and eventually destroy.

What do you think?

Comment: @aglet did you add the cloth modifier to the smoothed sphere? Or did you add the rigid body modifier?

Comment: Also curious if you have your blend file.